# ERROR: CASE types integer and boolean cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm getting the abovementioned error when trying to execute an `update` query. See below schema for reference.
[image]

The goal of the query is to update the capital row of the client table to be the same as the solde row of the compte table if the client has a compte. If they do not, the value of capital must be 0. I tried the below query and the error message mentioned in the title appeared.

```
UPDATE client
SET capital = (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN client_compte.compte_num IS NOT NULL THEN client.capital = compte.solde
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM compte 
JOIN client_compte ON compte.compte_num = client_compte.compte_num
JOIN client ON client_compte.client_id = client.client_id); 

Any help solving this error?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message seems quite clear -- the types of the columns do not match.  However, your `update` is malformed because of the two references to `client`.  Presumably, you intend:

```
UPDATE client cl
    SET capital = (CASE WHEN cc.compte_num IS NOT NULL
                        THEN cc.solde
                        ELSE 0
                   END)
    FROM client_compte cc JOIN
         compe c
         ON c.compte_num = cc.compte_num;
    WHERE cc.client_id = cl.client_id;
```

That fixes the error but is not exactly what you want.  I think a correlated subquery is better:

```
UPDATE client cl
    SET capital = COALESCE((SELECT cc.solde
                            FROM client_compte cc JOIN
                                 compte c
                                 ON c.compte_num = cc.compte_num
                            WHERE cc.client_id = cl.client_id
                           ), 0
                          );
```

Comment: I have corrected the first line of my SQL query. I need to update the `client` table and not the `compte` table. Also, we have not learned the `coalesce` argument yet. Is there a way to do this without the `coalesce` argument?

Comment: @SkippyDingleChalk . . . It is the same idea but with the table names reversed.

Comment: yes this works after removing the extra ; on the `ON` line. Was generating a syntax error otherwise.